# Execute external application and exit

Tags: windows, perl, exec

I am running ActiveState perl 5 on win7 x64. The solution does not have to be cross-platform.

I'm trying to use a Perl script to build a somewhat complex and variable command line argument string for another application. Then I want to execute that external application using the argument string while also immediately exiting the Perl script.

The idea is to create shortcut icons that run the Perl script with different arguments, which should generate the proper command line, spawn the external app (feeding it the proper arguments), and then go away immediately.

I can't seem to find any way to do this. It works if I use `exec()` and run the script from a command-line window (it returns to the command prompt right away after spawning the external app) but if I create a Windows shortcut using the same command, the Perl script just hangs around in the background forever until the spawned external app exits or I manually close the perl command window.

Is there any way to do this? I've tried `system`, `exec`, backticks, a couple of other obscure things. Nothing is working.

Comment: `perldoc -f exec` or maybe [Win32::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Process)

Comment: As I mentioned, already tried exec. But had not tried Win32::Process - and that did the trick, thanks a lot!!

Comment: You might have been able to get the same result using `exec "start => @cmdline"`, but you don't show code, so I don't have anything to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec` doesn't exist on Windows. (Perl tries to emulate it.)

If you use `system` or `readpipe` (aka backticks), Perl will continue to run until the child finishes (although it will be idle).

You need [Win32::Process](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Process) or `system('start "" ...')`.

Comment: Yes, Win32::Process was the solution.